# How to use the checkr package with learnr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, learnr

The [exercise tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/exercises.html) to the `learnr` package refers to the `checkr` packages:

> The [checkr](https://github.com/dtkaplan/checkr) package currently provides code checking functions that are compatible with learnr.

(Be aware that this reference does **not** point to the CRAN package [checkr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=checkr). Unfortunately, there is a duplicate package name.)

But in the `learnr` tutorial there is no advice how to use it together with `checkr`. On the other hand, the vignette in `checkr` is still a draft version, discusses advanced issues and is lacking an easy example in relation to `learnr`.

What I am looking for is a concrete procedure of a model example. For instance: How to check student input with the `two-plus-two`example, provided by the `learnr`R Markdown template "Interactive Tutorials".

So my question is: How to check with `learnr` the R code required to add two plus two using the `checkr` package?

---

Maybe this questions should use new tags (`learnr` and `checkr`) but I do not have the privileges to do so.

Comment: Check the link to the vignette: https://github.com/dtkaplan/checkr/blob/master/vignettes/checkr.Rmd

Answer (score 1):

After many experiments the following procedure worked for me:

1. I have started a new project and loaded the R Markdown template
   "Interactive Tutorial" and named it "01-Exercises". RStudio
   generated a folder this name and put my "01-Exercises.Rmd" in this
   folder.
2. I have added the line `tutorial_options(exercise.checker =
   checkr::check_for_learnr)` to the setup chunk of my
   "01-Exercises.Rmd" file.
3. I have added a new R chunk with the label `two-and-two-check`. (= The same name as the chunk name of the student task but added `-check`.)
4. In this R chunk I have added just one line `check_two_and_two(USER_CODE)` which will become my test function.
5. I have written a test function `check_two_and_two` in an extra script file "check_test.R" and saved under a folder "www".
6. I have sourced this script to the function into the memory. I ran `rmarkdown::run("01-Exercises/01-Exercises.Rmd")` from the console.

And here is my test function:

```
check_two_and_two <- function(USER_CODE) {
    code <- for_checkr(USER_CODE)
    t1 <- line_where(code, insist(all(F == "+"), "Your operator is {{F}}. This is not the assigned task."))
    if (failed(t1)) return(t1)
    t2 <- line_where(code, insist(all(V == 4), "Your solution is {{V}}. This is not the result (= 4) asked for."))
    if (failed(t2)) return(t2)
    line_binding(code, 2 + 2, failif(FALSE, "The pattern did not match."), message = "The result is correct, but I was looking for 2 + 2.")
}
```

Even if this worked for me: Maybe there is a better (more effective) solution?